# Are Ankles to be covered for women? if not, till what extent the garment can be(above the ankles)?

Tags: women, hijab, awrah

According to the hadith [Jami` at-Tirmidhi Book 24 Hadith 1731](https://muflihun.com/tirmidhi/24/1731) 
my understanding is that a woman has to wear a long garment which is below the ankle by at least a handspan or forearm. (That's what i understand by 'slacken')

> Narrated Ibn 'Umar:
>   That the Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) said: "Whoever arrogantly drags his garment, Allah will not look at him on the Day of Judgement." So Umm Salamah said: "What should the women do with their hems?" He said: "Slacken them a handspan." So she said: "Then their feet will be uncovered." He said: "Then slacken them a forearm's length and do not add to that."

While according to the [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/60131/ruling-on-women-wearing-pants-under-a-short-garment)

> If it is short and comes a handspan above the ankles, that is not permissible even if she covers her calves and feet with pants or socks, because that is imitating men who are enjoined to make their garments short, above the ankles.

Here they seem to have set handspan in the other direction i.e. it is allowed according to the fatwa to be above the ankle as long as it is not risen by more than handspan from the ankle.

**Question:Are Ankles to be covered for women? if not, till what extent the lower garment can be(above the ankles)?**

Comment: The scholars hold different opinions the majority says the feet must be covered. While the hanafis allow disclosing them.

Comment: Those who allow disclosing the feet, this question is directed towards them.

Answer (score 1):

Ankles and calves must be covered in front of non-mahrams. This is apparent from the verse:

> #### ولا يضربن بأرجلهن ليعلم ما يخفين من زينتهن
>
> And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:31](https://quran.com/24/31?translations=20)</sup>

As it refers to the sound of the anklets which are worn on the ankle and calves, and these have been described as hidden adornments.

The majority opinion is that feet of a non-mahram women are 'awrah. That is because the majority of jurists relied on the following hadith, which does not make an exception for the feet:

> #### إن المرأة إذا بلغت المحيض لم تصلح أن يرى منها إلا هذا وهذا ‏.‏ وأشار إلى وجهه وكفيه
>
> When a woman reaches the age of menstruation, it does not suit her that she displays her parts of body except this and this, and he pointed to his face and hands.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4104)</sup>

While some of the Hanafis say that the قدمين are also not 'awrah, and قدم is the part of the foot *below* the ankle. The evidence used for the minority view is the athar of Aisha:

> و عن عائشة: ولا يبدين زينتهن إلا ما ظهر منها قال: الفتخ حلق من فضة يكون في أصابع الرجلين
>
> Aisha is reported to have said regarding the verse "do not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof" that it includes the ring worn on the toes
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Abi Hatim](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/2565#p1)</sup>

And also because this part of the foot becomes uncovered automatically when a person walks so they are included in what 'necessarily appears' as mentioned in the verse.

The fatwa you have linked to is talking about the outer clothing (jilbab\cloak) and it does not mean that the ankle can be naked, rather it would be covered with socks or the trousers.

Answer (score 1):

Questions: Are Ankles to be covered for women? if not, till what extent the lower garment can be(above the ankles)?

In our hanafi fiqh women’s whole body must be covered except the following five parts: Face, both palms, soles of both feet. (Dur-re- Mukhtār, pp. 95, vol. 2) However, according to a Muftā biĥī Qawl (valid verdict), the Ṣalāĥ of a woman will be valid even if her both hands, up to wrist, and feet, up to ankle, are completely uncovered. So in SALAH you can have your feet uncovered up to the ankles.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is permissable to not be covered are the face and the hands.

Narrated Aisha (the Prophet's wife): Asma, daughter of Abu Bakr, entered upon the Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) wearing thin clothes. The Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) turned his attention from her. He said: 'O Asma, when a woman reaches the age of menstruation, it does not suit her that she displays her parts of body except this and this, and he pointed to her face and hands.

Abu Dawud, Book 32, Number 4092

when I have clothing that I think show too much ankle I wear long socks and shoes that cover most of that area. May Allah guide you and grant his blessings upon you.